# Не получается переименовать пакет в Андроид студио: ru.site.app в ru.new-site.app. Дефис мешает. Ошибка: "Not a valid package name"

Tags: android, android-studio

Не получается переименовать пакет в Андроид Студио (функцией Rename Package) (Дефис мешает):

**ru.site.app**  в  **ru.new-site.app**

Ошибка: "Not a valid package name"

Из-за дефиса "-" (в новом названии: new-site) не переименовывает. Но что делать-то, сайты-то с дефисом есть?! :)

(Пробовал разные кавычки, апострофы, прямую/обратную/одинарную/двойную косую черту и некоторые др. знаки и разделители, не смог подобрать)

Comment: в градле и манифесте тоже переименовали? или эта ошибка еще ДО синхронизации возникает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так имя пакета это не доменное имя, просто внешне похоже. Нет никаких причин думать, что для них действуют одинаковые ограничения.

Используйте нижнее подчеркивание: `ru.new_site.app`